# How to animate object one by one?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animation my object one by one. I am using animate.css for animation. Say like I have 7 `li` item as in the example below, it is zoom all at time, but I want **product 1** will zoom 1st then 2,3.4---7 but each will be delay like 1s or 10ms something like:

```
  <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos1">product 1</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos2">product 2</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos3">product 3</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos4">product 4</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos5">product 5</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos6">product 6</li>
    <li class="animated zoomIn prod pos7">product 7</li>
```

I saw animate.css document said for delay use `-vendor-animation-delay: 2s;` I tried that but still not success yet.

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/6x9re4yf/

Additional I am also trying. Whenever I click on any of them object it will zoom out same like one by one. Any idea how can i do that?

Comment: You need a `@keyframes` and a reference selector for that animation.  You can see it here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `-vendor-animation-delay: 2s;` should be `animation-delay: 2s;`

This works fine:

```
 animation-delay: 2s;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0Lv8ycju/

> additional I am also trying. when ever I click on any of them object it will zoomout same like one by one. Any idea how can I do that

add an jquery event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".animated").click(function(){
      $(".hexagonarea li.pos1").delay(1).animate({width:"0px",height:   "0px"});
    $(".hexagonarea li.pos2").delay(500).animate({width:"0px",height: "0px"});        

        //add other pos3,pos4..... here

 });
});
```

take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/0Lv8ycju/

**Update:** you will also have to include jquery lib into the head of your document

I managed to do a simple loop with each() to zoumOut one by one with a small snippet so here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".animated").click(function(){
  var i=1; //delay time 
  var y=1;       
  $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {    
   $(".hexagonarea li.pos"+y).delay(1+i).animate({width:"0px",height:   "0px"});
    $(".hexagonarea li.pos"+y).css({overflow:"hidden"});
   i+=100;// increase this to increase delay time (miliseconds)
    y+=1;   
     });
   });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88aqmy45/

Comment: thank u so much this way work :) any idea how can do zoomOut when i click  any object then

Comment: @pagol check the updated code above works like a charm !

Comment: thanks again. i did update my file http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/88aqmy45/2/ can you help me figure out how to  to Back button work. i mean after zoomout i show another div with zoomin animation. it is work fine and there have one button called BACK. i want to i click back then this box will zoomout and all li (pos) will zoomin.

also i think my jquery code not so nice i repate 6 times same code for show div. may be it is better so nice way

Comment: i updated more.. my script working fine. but i want to know am i right proper way did my jquery code or not. also i repate same code again and again. i think it possible to make it simple by few line. any idea how  http://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/88aqmy45/3/

Comment: Read how to use loops, with jquery ,each() it is very easy and will save you lot of time and struggle. read here: https://api.jquery.com/each/

your jquery looks pretty much ok! i have wrap the li elements around an .each() loop to reduce the repeating code you had take a look:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lrggdzfo/